# Hide all button if one button is pressed

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

How can I hide all buttons if "one" button is pressed? Is that possible?

This is my code and all what I've tried:

```
import sys
from Tkinter import *
from ttk import Frame, Button, Label, Style
from ttk import Entry
import Tkinter


class AllButtons(Frame):


    def __init__(self, parent):    
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)           
        self.parent = parent       
        self.initUI()

    def callback(self, number):    
        print "click!", self, number

    def hide_me(self, event):
        event.widget.grid_forget(), self, event

    def initUI(self):

        self.parent.title("mGUI")
        Style().configure("TButton", padding=(0, 5, 0, 5),
            font='serif 20', background="Black", foreground="darkorange2",
            activebackground="red",activeforeground="red")

        self.columnconfigure(0, pad=3)
        self.columnconfigure(1, pad=3)
        self.columnconfigure(2, pad=3)
        self.columnconfigure(3, pad=3)

        self.rowconfigure(0, pad=3)
        self.rowconfigure(1, pad=3)
        self.rowconfigure(2, pad=3)
        self.rowconfigure(3, pad=3)
        self.rowconfigure(4, pad=3)


        Funk_1 = Button(self, text="Funk_1", command=lambda:self.callback(1))
        Funk_1.grid(row=1, column=0)

        Funk_2 = Button(self, text="Funk_2", command=lambda:self.callback(2))
        Funk_2.grid(row=1, column=1)

        Funk_3 = Button(self, text="Funk_3", command=lambda:self.callback(3))
        Funk_3.grid(row=1, column=3)        

        Funk_4 = Button(self, text="Funk_4", command=lambda:self.callback(4))
        Funk_4.grid(row=3, column=0)

        Funk_5 = Button(self, text="Funk_5", command=lambda:self.callback(5))
        Funk_5.grid(row=3, column=1)         

        Funk_6 = Button(self, text="Funk_6", command=lambda:self.callback(6))
        Funk_6.grid(row=3, column=3)            

        Funk_7 = Button(self, text="Funk_7", command=lambda:self.callback(7))
        Funk_7.grid(row=5, column=0)

        Funk_8 = Button(self, text="Funk_8", command=lambda:self.callback(8))
        Funk_8.grid(row=5, column=1)         

        Funk_9 = Button(self, text="Funk_9", command=lambda:self.callback(9))
        Funk_9.grid(row=5, column=3)

       Funk_1.bind('<Button-1>', self.hide_me)
        Funk_2.bind('<Button-1>', self.hide_me)
        Funk_3.bind('<Button-1>', self.hide_me)
        Funk_4.bind('<Button-1>', self.hide_me)


        self.pack()


    def main():

        mGUI = Tk()
        app = AllButtons(mGUI)
        mGUI.mainloop()  


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can control the state of a button. If you initialize the button with 'state=normal', you can use another button to call a method which disables the button.

```
self.Funk_1 = Button(self, text="Funk_1", state='normal', command=lambda:self.set_buttons)
self.Funk_1.grid(row=1, column=0)

def set_buttons(self):
    self.Funk_1.configure(state='disabled')
```

You can read more here; http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm

Comment: np - remember to mark your question as answered by ticking the answer you liked, this will also reward the person who answered your question with hard cold reputation for the effort :)

Answer (score 0):

It is easiest if you store the button's id in a list and then operate on the list. Your code stripped down to just the buttons and their callback.

```
from Tkinter import *
from functools import partial

class AllButtons():

    def __init__(self, parent):    
        self.parent = parent       
        self.initUI()
        Button(self.parent, text="Exit", command=self.parent.quit,
               bg="orange").grid(row=20, column=2)

    def callback(self, number):    
        """ removes all buttons not clicked
        """
        number=int(number)
        print "click!", number
        for ctr in range(len(self.button_list)):
            if ctr != number:  ## leave the button clicked
                print "Deleting button number", ctr+1
                self.button_list[ctr].grid_forget()

    def initUI(self):
        """ create 9 buttons and store their Tkinter ID's in a list
        """
        self.parent.title("mGUI")

        self.button_list=[]
        g_row=1
        g_col=1
        for ctr in range(9):
            ## creating button located at offset "ctr" in the list
            ## this is also the number sent to the callback
            funk=Button(self.parent, text="Funk_%d" % (ctr+1),
                        command=partial(self.callback, ctr))
            ## add each button's id to the list
            self.button_list.append(funk)
            funk.grid(row=g_row, column=g_col)
            g_col += 1
            if g_col > 3:
               g_row += 2
               g_col=1

if __name__ == '__main__':
        mGUI = Tk()
        app = AllButtons(mGUI)
        mGUI.mainloop()
```